# How i can remove here System.out.println()

Tags: java, object, intellij-idea, methods, system.out

Hello guys I would like to know how to remove in my code the system.out.println, because I am passing an object in a method. Thank you

The code is about the sum of two fractions, and I have to pass all the arguments in the two object and then use it in the class to make the sum and the subtraction of the two fraction, I really need help guys thank you so much.

Class

```java
package denominatore;

public class Frazione {
    private int numeratore;
    private int denominatore;

    public Frazione (int num, int den){
        numeratore = num;
        denominatore = den;
    }
    public void somma(Frazione frazioneForadori2){
        System.out.println("La somma è: ");
        System.out.println((numeratore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore())+(denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getNumeratore())+"\n--");
        System.out.println(denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore());
    }
    public void sottrazione(Frazione frazioneForadori2){
        System.out.println("La sottrazione è: ");
        System.out.println((numeratore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore())-(denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getNumeratore())+"\n--");
        System.out.println(denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore());
    }
    public int getNumeratore(){
        return numeratore;
    }
    public int getDenominatore(){
        return denominatore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as Images. What should the println be replaced with ?

Comment: You can remove system.out.println and add a variable to the following statement and return it to the expected method. Instead of printing.

Comment: please paste the code into your post (instead of an image), your problem can easily be solved ... typing it off is the biggest challenge here :)

Comment: You can simply remove the lines with ```System.out.println()``` but you possibly want to do something else then right? What else do you want to do instead of printing the output to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the result from each method, return it as a new `Frazione` (fraction) object. Just fill the calculated numerator and denominator into the new object. For example the `somma` (sum) method becomes:

```
public Frazione somma(Frazione frazioneForadori2){
    return new Frazione((numeratore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore())+(denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getNumeratore()),
            denominatore * frazioneForadori2.getDenominatore());
}
```

The `sottrazione` (subtraction/difference)  method is similar, I am leaving that to you.

In order to print out the result outside the method it’s probably practical to define a `toString` method for the `Frazione` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + numeratore + "\n--\n" + denominatore;
}
```

With this method in your class we can try out the revised `somma` method like this:

```
    System.out.println(new Frazione(5, 3).somma(new Frazione(7, 2)));
```

The output is:

> ```
> 31
> --
> 6
> ```

I believe it’s the same output that you got before.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this one is better.